# Get coordinates of cursor when a JVectorMap Region is clicked

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

It is possible to use JVectorMap's event to get the original click event, in order to access the cursor's coordinates?Something like:

```
               `onRegionClick: function (event, code){
        alert(event.pageX +" "+ event.PageY);
                }`
```

The code shown above does not work.
Any hints are appreciated, or ways to get the coordinates of the JVectorMap on click.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible. If you need coordinates of the click you can bind a callback to the click event of the container. See this [demo](http://jvectormap.com/examples/reverse-projection/) for the code example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.The demo does not work in IE.IE is the motive for  asking help in the first place...